# Amazon Linux 2 su command not found

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, sudo

even though I am already working with Linux for years somehow I can't figure out the following issue.

I am using the following docker image:

```
amazoncorretto:11.0.6
```

When going into that image

```
docker run -ti amazoncorretto:11.0.6
```

and executing

```
sudo
```

I end up with

```
bash-4.2# sudo
bash: sudo: command not found
bash-4.2#
```

So of course I installed `sudo`

```
bash-4.2# yum install sudo
```

And now I am ending up with the following result

```
bash-4.2# sudo
usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
usage: sudo -l [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user] [-u user] [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-T timeout] [-u user] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-T timeout] [-u user] file ...
bash-4.2#
```

So thats working fine, but

```
bash-4.2# su
bash: su: command not found
bash-4.2#
```

And that is the problem. I have to switch user and trying with stuff like

```
sudo -E -u user /bin/sh -c "..."
```

Is not really satisfying.

I want to use

```
su -c "..." user
```

I could not find any related post and I am confused why `sudo` is found but `su` not.

I even tried to find the file thinking it is about the `PATH`

where I ended up with

```
bash-4.2# find / -name "sudo"
/var/db/sudo
/usr/libexec/sudo
/usr/bin/sudo
/etc/pam.d/sudo
bash-4.2#
```

but

```
bash-4.2# find / -name "su"
/usr/share/locale/su
bash-4.2#
```

We are talking about **Amazon Linux 2** here.

I would appreciate any help on this!

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. See https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.30/sudo.man.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first I tried as a replacement for `su`:

```
sudo "PATH=$PATH" -E -u user /bin/sh -c "..."
```

but that ended up with another issue in the end.

That's why I investigated further why `su` is not available and finally found out that I had to install the following package

```
yum install -y util-linux
```

After that `su` has been available.